# How to compare and select the better GARCH model?

Tags: r, garch

I am reading [this article](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/ARIMA-GARCH-Trading-Strategy-on-the-SP500-Stock-Market-Index-Using-R) which is talking about a GARCH trading strategy. I follow the steps and tried different parameters like window size (stock historical data). From the back test, I can see that different window size can affect the result.

I would like to ask that if there is a way to compare different models so that I can choose a better one?

I have read [another thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248334/comparing-aic-between-arma-and-garch) that is talking about AIC as a selection criteria. I can also see that there is a log likelihood from R. But I am afraid I cannot compare them directly between these two models.

Here are graphs of log returns of N225, with different window size.

[image: Window size 100]
[image: Window size 300]